# dbSendquery giving format error

Tags: sqldf, rsqlite

I need to create a table and insert some values into it uisng r

```
 library(sqldf)
    Company_Master <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="Company Master.sqlite" )
    dbSendQuery(conn = Company_Master,
                "CREATE TABLE Company Master(
                Comp_name varchar
                Address varchar)
                ")
```

Till here no error is given.But after this when i want to insert some value into the table

```
dbSendQuery(conn = Company_Master, "INSERT INTO COMPANY MASTER
    VALUES('INFOSYS','abcLALA')")
```

I get error like

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "Master": syntax error
```

I found the format on https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-sqlite-part-1/ and don't seem to get any other format except if using dbCEATETABLE. What is wrong in this format? Please help